# Injecting routes into router-outlet throws 'boolean expression must not be null' error

Tags: angular, dart, angular-dart

I've just started using Angular Dart, I've been using the Routing tutorial at: https://angulardart.dev/tutorial/toh-pt5 as a reference but my application seems to blow up whenever passing my routes into router-outlet

I've tried declaring router-outlet on it's own without passing it routes, obviously this didn't create any errors but also didn't bring in the desired components.

route_paths.dart

```
class RoutePaths {
  static final loginPath = RoutePath(path: 'login');
  static final signUpPath = RoutePath(path: 'sign-up');
}
```

routes.dart

```
class Routes {
    static final login = RouteDefinition(
    routePath: RoutePaths.loginPath,
    component: login_component.LoginComponentNgFactory
  );

  static final signUp = RouteDefinition(
    routePath: RoutePaths.signUpPath,
    component: sign_up_component.SignUpComponentNgFactory
  );

  static final all = <RouteDefinition> [
    login,
    signUp,
    RouteDefinition.redirect(
      path: '',
      redirectTo: RoutePaths.loginPath.toUrl(),
    )
  ];
}
```

app_component.dart

```
@Component(
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: 'app_component.html',
  directives: [routerDirectives, NgIf],
  exports: [RoutePaths, Routes],
)

class AppComponent {}
```

app_component.html

```html
<h1>Hello there</h1>
<router-outlet [routes]="Routes.all"></router-outlet>
```

I expect my login path to be available to the user at runtime, instead I get "Hello there" on the page and the following error in the console:

> EXCEPTION: Failed assertion: boolean expression must not be null
>   STACKTRACE: 
>   dart:sdk_internal 11901:16                                                                                       get isNotEmpty
>   package:angular_router/src/directives/packages/angular_router/src/route_definition.dart 285:5                    assertValid
>   package:angular_router/src/directives/packages/angular_router/src/directives/router_outlet_directive.dart 82:14  set routes
>   package:music_portal/packages/music_portal/app_component.template.dart 69:25                                     detectChangesInternal
>   package:angular/src/bootstrap/packages/angular/src/core/linker/views/view.dart 58:7                              detectCrash
>   package:angular/src/bootstrap/packages/angular/src/core/linker/app_view.dart 377:7                               detectChanges
>   package:music_portal/packages/music_portal/app_component.template.dart 124:17                                    detectChangesInternal
>   package:angular/src/bootstrap/packages/angular/src/core/linker/views/view.dart 58:7                              detectCrash
>   package:angular/src/bootstrap/packages/angular/src/core/linker/app_view.dart 377:7                               detectChanges
>   package:angular/src/bootstrap/packages/angular/src/core/change_detection/host.dart 128:13                        [_runTickGuarded]
>   package:angular/src/bootstrap/packages/angular/src/core/change_detection/host.dart 83:12                         tick
>   package:angular/src/bootstrap/packages/angular/src/core/application_ref.dart 107:5                               [_loadedRootComponent]
>   package:angular/src/bootstrap/packages/angular/src/core/application_ref.dart 95:7                                
>   package:angular/src/bootstrap/packages/angular/src/core/change_detection/host.dart 186:26                        
>   package:angular/src/core/change_detection/packages/angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 132:18                     
>   dart:sdk_internal 28349:14                                                                                       run
>   package:angular/src/core/change_detection/packages/angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 129:18                     [_run]
>   dart:sdk_internal 28555:14                                                                                       run
>   package:angular/src/core/change_detection/packages/angular/src/core/zone/ng_zone.dart 291:23                     run
>   package:angular/src/bootstrap/packages/angular/src/core/application_ref.dart 139:52                              runInZone
>   package:angular/src/bootstrap/packages/angular/src/core/change_detection/host.dart 184:5                         run
>   package:angular/src/bootstrap/packages/angular/src/core/application_ref.dart 69:23                               bootstrap
>   package:angular/src/bootstrap/packages/angular/src/bootstrap/run.dart 207:16                                     runApp
>   main.dart 15:3                                                                                                   main
>   webdev/src/serve/injected/client.js 11440:45                                                                     $0
>   webdev/src/serve/injected/client.js 3424:26                                                                      
>   webdev/src/serve/injected/client.js 1188:72                                                                      
>   webdev/src/serve/injected/client.js 4914:23                                                                      $2
>   webdev/src/serve/injected/client.js 4906:30                                                                      $1
>   webdev/src/serve/injected/client.js 5475:40                                                                      iB
>   webdev/src/serve/injected/client.js 5477:30                                                                      dw
>   webdev/src/serve/injected/client.js 5078:13                                                                      $0
>   webdev/src/serve/injected/client.js 1240:41                                                                      cJ
>   webdev/src/serve/injected/client.js 4996:3                                                                       bz
>   webdev/src/serve/injected/client.js 4932:3                                                                       ai
>   webdev/src/serve/injected/client.js 4894:12                                                                      ai
>   webdev/src/serve/injected/client.js 1179:20                                                                      bN
>   webdev/src/serve/injected/client.js 3485:17                                                                      
>   webdev/src/serve/injected/client.js 1188:72                                                                      
>   webdev/src/serve/injected/client.js 4914:23                                                                      $2
>   webdev/src/serve/injected/client.js 4906:30                                                                      $1
>   webdev/src/serve/injected/client.js 5475:40                                                                      iB
>   webdev/src/serve/injected/client.js 5477:30                                                                      dw
>   webdev/src/serve/injected/client.js 5078:13                                                                      $0
>   webdev/src/serve/injected/client.js 1240:41                                                                      cJ
>   webdev/src/serve/injected/client.js 5044:3                                                                       $0
>   webdev/src/serve/injected/client.js 1268:5                                                                       uK
>   webdev/src/serve/injected/client.js 1270:7                                                                       uP
>   webdev/src/serve/injected/client.js 4865:3                                                                       $1
>   webdev/src/serve/injected/client.js 441:17                                                                       vk
>   webdev/src/serve/injected/client.js 449:51

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that when using Firefox to develop an Angular Dart application, it will 404 when looking for source map files.

```
Source map error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: http://localhost:8080/packages/build_web_compilers/src/dev_compiler/dart_sdk.js
Source Map URL: dart_sdk.js.map

Source map error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: http://localhost:8080/webdev/src/serve/injected/client.js
Source Map URL: client.dart.js.map
```

I honestly have no idea why Firefox blocks, or cannot find the source map files but switching to Chrome was the instant fix for the issue. I guess it makes sense considering they're both Google products.

EDIT: Possibly related github issue: https://github.com/dart-lang/build/issues/1788

Comment: This might also help other folks out there too if they want to add the source maps for Firefox? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Use_a_source_map

Comment: These `webdev` [docs](https://dart.dev/tools/webdev#serve) explicitly say that the `dartdevc` compiler only supports Chrome, which is used by default by `webdev serve`. To view in other browsers, you need to use `dart2js` which is default with `webdev build` or you can use `webdev serve --release`

Comment: I found this out not long after I started using Chrome again. the Dart compiler has some really weird quirks. I found out that you can also use pub to build an app, even though I assumed it was just a package manager!